# error with playing mkv files both in vlc and mplayer

Tags: 14.04, vlc, mplayer

I have 2 mkv files downloaded from the same place and when i try to open these files using vlc or mplayer only the sound will play and there is NO video.
what do you think is the problem?
ubuntu 14.04 64 bit

Comment: Please post vlc version & use mediainfo on mkv's & post audio, video codecs of file

Answer (score 0):

Install the Gstreamer plugins for proper working of video files in VLC or in any Video player.

To install Gstreamer plugins type in the following commands.

- Update your Repositories.

> sudo apt-get update

- Install the Gstreamer plugins

> sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly

After this you should be able to play almost all types on audio/video files on any player of your choice.

I too had the same problem and solved it by installing Gstreamer plugins.